# Lambda on Tkinter

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I want to make a game board using a Button, and when I click over the button they'll show 'X'. I have tried using a lambda function in the button. But it shows error 'Name Error: klik is not defined'. I confused how to solve that problem.

```
 def game(self):
     for baris in range(int(self.entry1.get())):
         for kolom in range(int(self.entry2.get())):
             self.button = Button(self.frameup, text=" ", height=5, width=10, command = lambda baris = baris, kolom=kolom: klik(self))

             self.button.grid ( row = baris, column = kolom)


 def klik(self):
     self.baris = Button(self.frameup, text = 'X', height=5, width=10)
     self.baris.grid( row =  baris, column = kolom)
```

Comment: Is this all inside a class? Did you mean `self.click()`? Please give a [mcve] including full error traceback.

Comment: when you click button (to set `X`) then you create second button and now you have two buttons in one cell. You could change text in existing button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying

```
command = lambda baris = baris, kolom=kolom: klik(self)
```

say

```
command = lambda baris = baris, kolom=kolom: self.klik(baris, kolom.
```

Also change your `klik` function definition to

```
def klik(self, baris, kolom):
```